# Angular 8: Disconnect from sockets when route params are going to change

Tags: angular, sockets

We are facing a problem that is probably obvious to solve but we do not manage to find the solution.

We have a component that doesn't reload because the route params change but the route is the same. Inside that component, we have some connections to sockets to receive data. With every specific route params we need to have new connections. The problem is that the connections before changing the route params are not going away because the ngOnDestroy event is obviously not firing.

Our question is: How can we disconnect from the sockets before going to the new route params?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm failing to see you problem. There must be some action with the effect that prompts the route params to change. Can you not add another effect to whatever that action might be that deconstructs the socket? When you construct new sockets can you not clear down old sockets?

Comment: Moreover, params are stored as `Observable<Params>` can you not subscribe and clear down sockets when the value changes?

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the route events and reconnect your socket at the `NavigationEnd` event.

```
import { NavigationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';


class YourComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(private router: Router) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.router.events
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.destroy$),
        filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd),
      )
      .subscribe(event => {
        // Do something
        // Reconnect you socket
      });

  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {

    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();

  }
}
```